# Track Resource deletion from Azure ActivityLog in LogAnalytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to alert/visualize Resource changes like creation/deletion of Azure resources using Log Analytics/OMS.
I am able to find new deployments using:

```
AzureActivity 
| where ActivityStatus  == 'Succeeded' and OperationNameValue contains  'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/write'
```

and VM start/stop also is traceable.

However, i do not see any logs when a VM is deleted from a resource group. I checked in the resource group Activity logs too, however such an important event doesnt seem to be tracked properly. Only thing I find is the deletion of shutdown schedules as part of VM deletion, however this isnt a reliable indicator.

How can I track resource deletions using Log Analytics?

Comment: you can set up an alert in log analytics when vm is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up an alert when the vm is deleted in log analytics.

Nav to azure portal, your log analytics -> in the left blade, select Alerts -> New alert rule-> in the new page, select your vm as resource -> then in the condition, add an condition: Delete Virtual Machine.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. i enabled all administrative alerts at the subscription level and now getting alerts as expected.

Comment: BTW, shouldn't there be an option to enable these events to be logged to the activity log without having to create an alert??? I would definitely like to see resource update/delete actions taken by users in the activity log.